# Mailgun MailChimp DNS Record Conflict

Tags: email, dns, mailchimp, mailgun

To send emails using Mailgun and MailChimp so that it comes from your domain, an DNS TXT Record needs to be added:

Mailgun advises using a subdomain (I do not know why) and the record looks like this:

`host: mg
value: v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all`

Thus I understand it sends email from the mg.expertbox.com domain

Mailchip assumes the root domain is used to send and requires the following (no option to specify subdomain):

`host: expertbox.com
value: v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all`

So this assumes sending from the root domain.

The Mailgun DNS record has been happily working and I do not want to break it, but I cannot add a seperate subdomain record on the DNS manager in my GoDaddy account where the domain is hosted. Adding any other TXT with value v=spf1 creates an error that duplicates are not allowed.

From my research on the topic, it seems I can use the value: `v=spf1 include:mailgun.org include:servers.mcsv.net ?all`, however that assumes both accounts are sending from the root.

How do I solve this conundrum? Why does Mailgun advise using a subdomain, while MailChimp forces using the root? Will MailGun work if I just change the value and keep the host name 'mg'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the same subdomain in MailChimp that you use in Mailgun. I think it's just that the MailChimp documentation specifies a root domain. I don't think that means you *can't* use a subdomain, it's just that it uses a root domain as an example in the documentation. You can verify a subdomain for MailChimp as long as you have a working email address at that subdomain. Try it.

As for your SPF record, keep in mind that the `?ALL` authorization type is "neutral" so is of little value. Use the softfail: `~ALL`. Here's a complete list:

• -ALL - Fail unauthorized email (useful)
• ~ALL - Softfail unauthorized email (useful)
• ?ALL - Neutral regarding how email's handled (not typically useful)
• +ALL - Pass all email authorized or unauthorized (not useful)

So assuming that MailChimp and Mailgun are the two services you're authorizing to send outgoing mail for the subdomain in question, here's your SPF record:

**host:** `mg`
**value:** `v=spf1 include:mailgun.org include:servers.mcsv.net ~all`

You will still need an SPF record for your root domain as well that includes any service you want to authorize to send outgoing email on your behalf. Your mx record indicates Godaddy. If you send outgoing email with Godaddy then you'd want to `include: spf.secureserver.net` in the root domain's SPF record, though I'd double check Goddaddy's docs to make sure it's not changed very recently. By the way, the reason I recommend the `~ALL` rather than the more strict `-ALL` is that it's easy to forget to add something you use for outgoing email and it's easy to forget to change the SPF when changing to another service for email.

Then, after you have the SPF record for both `mg` and your root domain, validate both using a tool such as the [SPF Survey.](https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/)

Comment: I changed the mg value as per your suggestion but did not add an SPF record to the root yet, and it seems to work (the email arrives and MailChimp is no longer asking for authentication. SPF Survey, however, finds no SPF records, mailgun also still works, and I can still send email from Apple Mail using the smtp account. 

I'm not sure I do not understand why I need the SPF record for the root domain. I have an CNAME and MX for the GoDaddy smtp server.

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps that did not work, I check the email headers and it seems MailChimp is still using the MailChimp servers to send the email.

MailChimp: 
Sender: ⁨"The Expert Box" <info=expertbox.com@mail35.suw11.mcdlv.net>⁩

MailGun: 
Sender: ⁨info=expertbox.com@mg.expertbox.com⁩

Comment: No... it worked, but I had to click on the Authenticate button in MailChimp before it started using it. Still not using a root domain though...

Comment: Cool. Also, note that you can do DKIM at MailChimp for this subdomain as well and it's a very good idea.

Comment: DNS stuff is not really my forté, why is DKIM in addition to SPF a good idea?

Comment: Typo in last comment DNN changed to DNS.  
It’s a good idea because it helps protect your domain name’s rep. You put a public key in your DNS and the private key resides with the service sending your email, signing each email you send, vouching not only that you sent it or authorized it to be sent but also that nobody altered the email in transit.